# 2012 SERVER DCDIAG STRUGGLE with error 1355 (DsGetDdName call failed)

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, domain-controller

*EDIT: This problem was resolved by following the information found at this link:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/947022/the-netlogon-share-is-not-present-after-you-install-active-directory-d
Essentially, NETLOGON/SYSVOL were not being shared, by following the directions above the issue was resolved.

Thanks joeqwerty for your replies.*

I'm two days into this problem on a 2012 Server install. Previous server had crashed, 2012 software reinstalled, all patches applied.  Active Directory is non-functional after promoting to DC (this is the sole DC in a new Forest).  DNS seems to be functioning correct.

I believe this entire problem relates to the following error message received while installing AD:

> "The DNS Server was unable to create the built-in directory partition
>   ForestDnsZones.CLINIC.LAN.  The error was 9906."

But it may just be another symptom.

DCDIAG information is below, but the first failure, error 1355, has me stuck.

```
nltest /DsGetDc:clinic.lan 
Getting DC name failed: Status = 1355 0x54b ERROR_NO_SUCH_DOMAIN
```

This domain is now named "CLINIC" whereas before it was named "MEDICAL".  This was done intentionally to avoid a conflict when workstations were added.  Also, the Windows install was done from a Dell "Recover" operation, where it essentially stuck all the old stuff in a directory "Windows.old" and just created a new version of Windows beside it.

I've been through this process twice with no difference in the outcome.

Getting pretty desperate as users are down.

I will greatly appreciate any suggestions that might lead me to an approach to solving this problem.  Have read just about everything I can find online to no avail.

```
NSLOOKUP CLINIC.LAN returns:

Server: UnKnown
Address: 10.1.10.200

Name:  clinic.lan
Address: 10.1.10.200
```

This is the correct IP Address but I don't know what to make of the reply.

Thanks, again for any help anyone can provide.  The entire DCDIAG is listed below.

> Directory Server Diagnosis
>
> Performing initial setup:
>
> Trying to find home server...
>
> Home Server = WINSERV
>
> - Identified AD Forest.     Done gathering initial info.
>
> Doing initial required tests
>
> ```
>    Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\WINSERV
>
>   Starting test: Connectivity
>
>      ......................... WINSERV passed test Connectivity
> ```
>
> Doing primary tests
>
> ```
>    Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\WINSERV
>
>   Starting test: Advertising
>
>      Fatal Error:DsGetDcName (WINSERV) call failed, error 1355
>
>      The Locator could not find the server.
>
>      ......................... WINSERV failed test Advertising
>
>   Starting test: FrsEvent
>
>      ......................... WINSERV passed test FrsEvent
>
>   Starting test: DFSREvent
>
>      There are warning or error events within the last 24 hours after the
>
>      SYSVOL has been shared.  Failing SYSVOL replication problems may cause
>
>      Group Policy problems. 
>      ......................... WINSERV failed test DFSREvent
>
>   Starting test: SysVolCheck
>
>      ......................... WINSERV passed test SysVolCheck
>
>   Starting test: KccEvent
>
>      ......................... WINSERV passed test KccEvent
>
>   Starting test: KnowsOfRoleHolders
>
>      ......................... WINSERV passed test KnowsOfRoleHolders
>
>   Starting test: MachineAccount
>
>      ......................... WINSERV passed test MachineAccount
>
>   Starting test: NCSecDesc
>
>      ......................... WINSERV passed test NCSecDesc
>
>   Starting test: NetLogons
>
>      Unable to connect to the NETLOGON share! (\\WINSERV\netlogon)
>
>      [WINSERV] An net use or LsaPolicy operation failed with error 67,
>
>      The network name cannot be found..
>
>      ......................... WINSERV failed test NetLogons
>
>   Starting test: ObjectsReplicated
>
>      ......................... WINSERV passed test ObjectsReplicated
>
>   Starting test: Replications
>
>      ......................... WINSERV passed test Replications
>
>   Starting test: RidManager
>
>      ......................... WINSERV passed test RidManager
>
>   Starting test: Services
>
>      ......................... WINSERV passed test Services
>
>   Starting test: SystemLog
>
>      A warning event occurred.  EventID: 0x00001695
>
>         Time Generated: 09/09/2019   10:24:34
>
>         Event String:
>
>         Dynamic registration or deletion of one or more DNS records associated with DNS domain 'MEDICAL.LAN.' failed.  These
> ```
>
> records are used by other computers to locate this server as a domain
>   controller (if the specified domain is an Active Directory domain) or
>   as an LDAP server (if the specified domain is an application
>   partition).
>
> ```
>      An error event occurred.  EventID: 0xC00038D6
>
>         Time Generated: 09/09/2019   10:49:13
>
>         Event String:
>
>         The DFS Namespace service could not initialize cross forest trust information on this domain controller, but it will
> ```
>
> periodically retry the operation. The return code is in the record
>   data.
>
> ```
>      ......................... WINSERV failed test SystemLog
>
>   Starting test: VerifyReferences
>
>      ......................... WINSERV passed test VerifyReferences
>
>
>    Running partition tests on : Schema
>
>   Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
>
>      ......................... Schema passed test CheckSDRefDom
>
>   Starting test: CrossRefValidation
>
>      ......................... Schema passed test CrossRefValidation
>
>    Running partition tests on : Configuration
>
>   Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
>
>      ......................... Configuration passed test CheckSDRefDom
>
>   Starting test: CrossRefValidation
>
>      ......................... Configuration passed test CrossRefValidation
>
>    Running partition tests on : CLINIC
>
>   Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
>
>      ......................... CLINIC passed test CheckSDRefDom
>
>   Starting test: CrossRefValidation
>
>      ......................... CLINIC passed test CrossRefValidation
>
>    Running enterprise tests on : CLINIC.LAN
>
>   Starting test: LocatorCheck
>
>      Warning: DcGetDcName(GC_SERVER_REQUIRED) call failed, error 1355
>
>      A Global Catalog Server could not be located - All GC's are down.
>
>      Warning: DcGetDcName(TIME_SERVER) call failed, error 1355
>
>      A Time Server could not be located.
>
>      The server holding the PDC role is down.
>
>      Warning: DcGetDcName(GOOD_TIME_SERVER_PREFERRED) call failed, error
>
>      1355
>
>      A Good Time Server could not be located.
>
>      Warning: DcGetDcName(KDC_REQUIRED) call failed, error 1355
>
>      A KDC could not be located - All the KDCs are down.
>
>      ......................... CLINIC.LAN failed test LocatorCheck
>
>   Starting test: Intersite
>
>      ......................... CLINIC.LAN passed test Intersite
> ```

Comment: Had same DISAAAASTERRR after upgrade from 2008 R2 to 2012 R2. Suddenly whole forest fell down. Was restoring DCs from backups several times with same outcome.
This link was a survival for me.

Answer (score 0):

> I've been through this process twice with no difference in the
>   outcome. Getting pretty desperate as users are down. I will greatly
>   appreciate any suggestions that might lead me to an approach to
>   solving this problem. Have read just about everything I can find
>   online to no avail.

I'm pretty sure my original comment was a pretty solid push in the right direction. Additionally, nothing in my original comment was condescending, rude, or unprofessional. Yet you took umbrage with it for some reason. Here we are 2 hours later and you still don't have an answer to your question and your problem is still unresolved. You could have opened a support case with MS in that time and probably had the issue resolved by now. But you keep on being stubborn and offended. That'll get it fixed.

That being said, do you receive the same error message when trying to create the domain from scratch for two different attempts? Are you reinstalling Windows from scratch? What is the server using for DNS when you attempt to DCPROMO it? Are you installing Windows on bare metal or in a VM? Where did you get the installation media?

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting this during the promo: "A delegation for this DNS server cannot be created because the authoritative parent zone cannot be found or it does not run Windows DNS server."

This is a small office, standalone server, no VM.  The installation media was apparently bought with the Server a few years ago, it is Dell OEM.  I have tried installing AD both ways and the result was identical.  

The DCPROMO process does not appear to be sharing SYSVOL or NETLOGON, which I assume to relate to the DNS problem above.  THANK YOU.

Comment: The DNS delegation error is expected and can be ignored. The DCPROMO process will try to create a delegation for the subdomain in the parent zone and upon failing to do that will generate that error. In your case no delegation can be created or is needed.

Comment: This error would be more apparent if your AD domain were something like AD.COMPANY.COM. Then DCPROMO would attempt to create a delegation for the AD subdomain in the parent COMPANY.COM domain for this server. You don't normally need a delegation unless you actually need clients that query the COMPANY.COM domain to be able to resolve queries in the AD subdomain... which you normally don't need. This error isn't the cause of your problem.

Comment: Take a look at the Application, System, Directory Service, and DNS Server event logs on the server. Filter the logs for Critical, Warning, and Error events and post what you find in your question. This sounds like a DNS issue, but the fact that it's occurring during repeated DCPROMO attempts is strange.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions.  This is a very strange problem to me.  I just did the install again, breaking it up into DNS first, then AD then promoting.  

I cannot add AD, as I get a message that "Naming information cannot be located".

It is also not sharing the NETLOGON and SYSVOL.  I suppose I need to just nuke the entire existing drive and do a clean install.  Hard to do over a remote connection from 2000 miles away.  Thank you for your suggestions

Comment: The following link has solved the problems with sysvol & netlogon not getting shared.  

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/947022/the-netlogon-share-is-not-present-after-you-install-active-directory-d 

Still have some issue related to group policy, but much more approachable.  Will follow up with update for any other users who encounter this odd problem.